# polish characters utf8 dont show right

Tags: php, html, utf-8

Currently my site supports English, portuguese, swedish and polish. But for some reason some polish characters dont show right, like `Zal�z konto` it should look like this `Zalóz konto`

I have this

```
// Send the Content-type header in case the web server is setup to send something else
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and inside `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: From where you get polish texts? If from database you need to set also database encoding after mysql_connect function.

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Database? Make sure the connection is set to UTF-8 (SET NAMES for MySQL). Hard-coded? Make sure you save the file with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: thanks! i saved the file with utf8

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert your string to UTF8 also.

utf8_encode() does not check what encoding your string was in, and sometimes it gives you a messed up string, so I made a function called Encoding::toUTF8() to do this right.

You dont need to know what the encoding of your strings is.  It can be Latin1 (iso 8859-1), Windows-1252 or UTF8, or the string can have a mix of them.  Encoding::toUTF8() will convert everything to UTF8.

I did it because a service was giving me a feed of data all messed up, mixing those encodings in the same string.

Usage:

```
$utf8_string = Encoding::toUTF8($mixed_string);

$latin1_string = Encoding::toLatin1($mixed_string);
```

I've included another function, Encoding::fixUTF8(), wich will fix every UTF8 string that looks garbled product of having been encoded into UTF8 multiple times.

Usage:

```
$utf8_string = Encoding::fixUTF8($garbled_utf8_string);
```

Examples:

```
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃ©dÃ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dÃÂ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂÃÂ©dÃÂÃÂ©ration Camerounaise de Football");
echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dération Camerounaise de Football");
```

will output:

```
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
Fédération Camerounaise de Football
```

Download:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/186012/PHP/forceUTF8.zip

Answer (score 4):

I start my header with:

```
< head>
    < meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pl" >
    < meta charset="UTF-8" >
    ...
< /head>
...
```

and all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

if you retrieve the data from mysql database with php you should use this query before do anything..

`mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`

So data received from db will be properly encoded, if they was properly stored in it...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the [iso-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) standard:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```