# PHP inserts weird symbols instead of polish letters

Tags: php, html, mysql

When i'm inserting data from mysql database using this code it doesn't fill polish letters instead it shows random weird symbols instead of polish letters Also it seems that it's problem from database site yet i have it on utf8_polish_ci:
[PHP shows symbols instead of letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HfJI.png)

```php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","blank","blank","blank");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Nie Udało się połączyć z bazą danych: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Delegacje");

    echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Imię i Nazwisko</th>
<th>Data od</th>
<th>Data do</th>
<th>Miejsce wyjazdu</th>
<th>Miejsce przyjazdu</th>
</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Imie i Nazwisko'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Data od'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Data do'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Miejsce wyjazdu'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Miejsce przyjazdu'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You have to change the database collation to polish

Comment: You should use utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: I did both and it didnt work

Comment: You need to decode stuff from DB inside php, check this out: [polish utf8 php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291872/polish-characters-utf8-dont-show-right)

Comment: You should use `utf8mb4` both on column level and on connection level

Answer (score -2):

Try opening file in regular notepad go save as and under encoding chose UTF-8, that could help too.